# Как сделать шаблон для содержимого стандартного баллуна?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, шаблонизаторы

Я подгружаю JSON в objectManager. В JSONe в properties находятся balloonContentHeader, Body и тп. В Body находится много вёрстки и её хотелось бы шаблонизировать. Если попробовать задать objectManager.objects.balloonContentBody = "вёрстка", то не сработает. Через фабрику я ранее делал, но то создание кастомного шаблона, а мне нужно вёрстку внутрь стандартного посадить. При этом, разумеется, шаблон должен хватать properties и подставлять их.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормальный способ это сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример того, что вы хотите получить. Распишите ваш вопрос подробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашёл вариант сам

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "datanew.json",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (json) {
                    $.each(json.features, function (i, item) {
                        var placemark = {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            id: item.id,
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: item.coordinates,
                            },
                            properties: {
                                balloonContentHeader: "<h5>Заявка " + item.id +"</h5><small><em>" + item.properties.user + "</em></small>",
                                balloonContentBody: [
                                    "<div class='balloon-row'>",
                                        "<div class='balloon-image'>",
                                            "<a href='" + item.properties.image_full + "' class='image-link'>",
                                                "<img src='" + item.properties.image_small + "' class='image-link-img' alt=''>",
                                            "</a>",
                                        "</div>",
                                        "<div class='balloon-content'>",
                                            "<div><strong>Местоположение ямы:</strong></div>",
                                            "<p>" + item.properties.location + "</p>",
                                            "<div><strong>Описание</strong></div>",
                                            "<p>" + item.properties.description + "</p>",
                                        "</div>",
                                        "<hr class='hr'>",
                                    "</div>",
                                    "<div class='balloon-row'>",
                                        "<div class='balloon-image'>",
                                            "<a href='" + item.properties.image_result_full + "' class='image-link'>",
                                                "<img src='" + item.properties.image_result_small + "' class='image-link-img' alt=''>",
                                            "</a>",
                                        "</div>",
                                        "<div class='balloon-content'>",
                                            "<div><strong>Статус:</strong></div>",
                                            "<p>" + item.properties.status + "</p>",
                                        "</div>",
                                    "</div>"
                                ].join(''),
                                balloonContentFooter: "",
                                clusterCaption: "Заявка #" + item.id,
                                hintContent: "<strong>Заявка #" + item.id + "</strong>"
                            },
                        }
                        placemarks.features.pushIfNotExist(placemark, function (e) {
                            return e.id === placemark.id;
                        });
                    });
                    objectManager.add(placemarks);
```